# Karel Robot in Python for teaching students

Tags: python, karel

Have a nice morning,

Together with a lecturer I am preparing the world of the robot Karl for teaching Python at the university, which not only memories are surely familiar.

The world is already ready, the application uses the TKInter library. I have a question for more experienced Pythonists, when I try to run it in the command line I see two empty TKInter windows with the message "Exception thrown! The given robot world has already been removed." and similarly in IDLE.

Since the project is also available with images, I saved it using the repository service uschovna.cz here - [Karel Robot](https://www.uschovna.cz/en/zasilka/QLSEUY8MN4STTK7C-S5K//?set_lang=en) .

I confess that I am not yet very friendly with TKInter, but it has been selected for teaching, so it is possible that I just need to add one or two methods to the robotwindow.py class and everything will work as it should.

### Here is a list of error messages:

```
Starting with command line:

>>> from robot import *

===== Module robot.color ===== START
===== Module robot.color ===== STOP
===== Module robot.dir4 ===== START
===== Module robot.dir4 ===== STOP
===== Module robot.robotworld ===== START
===== Module robot.robotworld ===== STOP
===== Module robot.robotwindow ===== START
=== ROBOTS_ICON_DI­RECTORY = '/home/wanbli/ro­bot/IMGR/'
===== Module robot.robotwindow ===== STOP

>>> rwd = new_empty_world(3, 3)

>>> rww = create_window_for(rwd)

I see two empty TK windows and message "Exception thrown! The given robot has already been removed.".

---

Starting with IDLE:

>>> from robot import *

##### Package with classes implementing the world of the robot Karel.

===== Module robot.color ===== START

===== Module robot.color ===== STOP

===== Module robot.dir4 ===== START

===== Module robot.dir4 ===== STOP

===== Module robot.robotworld ===== START

===== Module robot.robotworld ===== STOP

===== Module robot.robotwindow ===== START

=== ROBOTS_ICON_DI­RECTORY = '/home/wanbli/ro­bot/IMGR/'

===== Module robot.robotwindow ===== STOP

>>> rwd = new_empty_world(3, 3); rwd

<robot.robotwor­ld.RobotWorld object at 0x00000181D4D86830>

>>> rww = create_window_for(rwd); rww

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>

rww = create_window_for(rwd); rww

File "/home/wanbli/ro­bot/robotwindow­.py", line 104, in create_window_for

window = RobotWindow(world)

File "/home/wanbli/ro­bot/robotwindow­.py", line 34, in __init__

for _ in range(world.rows)]

File "/home/wanbli/ro­bot/robotworld­.py", line 202, in rows

self._check_wor­ld_alive()

File "/home/wanbli/ro­bot/robotworld­.py", line 382, in _check_world_alive

raise RWError(msg)

robot.robotwor­ld.RWError:

The robot world in question has already been removed.
```

---

Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Ludek Stastny

Answer (score 0):

The problem is already solved, I moved everything I needed to the initor file. For those interested, a link to the functional version:

https://www.uschovna.cz/zasilka/QOXD2UBSWRYE8RP6-GFW/